# Error: Cannot find module '/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/Projects/MYPROJECTNAME'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to compile Node with TypeScript, and I'm fairly new to it.

I noticed that my /src files were not being reflected when I updated them and ran the server.

I decided to try to delete the /dist folder, as I thought maybe this would remove any caching.

Now whenever I try to run `npm start`

I get the following:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/Projects/MYPROJECTNAME'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:668:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:591:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
```

I assume some file is just missing? The /dist directory was recreated.

How do I get rid of this error?

Sorry if this is a basic question, but I am just not finding any resources for what I screwed up here.

Full tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "allowJs": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "node_modules/*"
            ]
        },
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/controllers/customer/userAPIController.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: what is in package.json scripts: start part?

Comment: "start": "node .",

Comment: show tsconfig.json then  (since You're compiling TS code)

Comment: @num8er Posted the full tsconfig.json in the body text above

Comment: what's in dist folder? index.js?

Comment: No, there's no index.js. I suspect there needs to be? The build process only created controllers, db, and models directories. How do I generate a proper /dist folder from the /src folder? I've tried npm run build

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205837/discussion-between-num8er-and-cecil-rodriguez).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that there was no index.js in the newly build /dist directory.

While this probably isn't the best way to do this in the long term, I got around it by manually compiling the index.ts file in the /src directory and copying it to the dist folder.

```
cd src
tsc --esModuleInterop index.ts
cp index.js ../dist/index.js
```

Comment: it's fine if it's solves Your problem. Even You can make it as part of build command by adding to the end of it: `&& cd src && tsc --esModuleInterop index.ts && cp index.js ../dist/index.js`